# error when running spotify python script

Tags: python, macos, spotify, libspotify

Hi I am trying to run a script for spotify that is python called starrify on my mac
https://github.com/swinton/starrify

I am getting this error when I run it

```
error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"/Users/hnewbs/Documents/star/starrify.py\", line 7, in <module>
from spotify import Link
ImportError: No module named spotify" number 1
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

I fixed it by reinstall pyspotify by following these instructions http://labs.tinkerista.com/?p=9

Comment: Requirements: Install libspotify and pyspotify.  Have you installed these dependencies?

Comment: I have installed them both and reinstalled them

Comment: This is beyond my experience.  I think you have to integrate the libspotify module into python.  You might need to create a wrapper function in c to use libspotify with python.  I am looking [at this site](http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/) for details.  This is beyond my experience and since I do not plan on getting a premium spotify account, I wish you luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

`pyspotify` is not installed correctly (or you are not running the same python interpreter you used to install it).  You can install it with `pip install pyspotify`.  You then should be able to `import spotify` in a script and have it succeed.  You might also try running the `pyspotify` [example script](https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify/blob/develop/examples/jukebox.py) first.